# How to fill JSON array with strings, divided by comma

Tags: angularjs, json

I got a JSON which needs to look like this:

```
...
"Participants":[  
  "aaa@bbb.com",
  "ccc@ddd.com"
],
...
```

And a `<textarea>`, which is filled with emailaddresses, divided by commas like this:

```
aaa@bbb.com, baz@foo.com, asdf@bar.com
```

How can I add the separated strings to the $scope.Participants with ng-model="poll.Participants" ?

Comment: will need to write directive that requires `ngModel`.  [This article](http://radify.io/blog/understanding-ngmodelcontroller-by-example-part-1/) explains it well